# How to disable breaks at ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet

Tags: windbg

How do I disable debugger breaks in `ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet` instruction?

E.g.:

```
7:022> g
eax=7754dcf9 ebx=006a1be8 ecx=006a0e40 edx=006a0d18 esi=80300002 edi=00000000
eip=77736954 esp=004afe0c ebp=004afe28 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
77736954 c3              ret
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the callstack, where is this originating from? That might be the problem you want to actually debug. See: http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2008/01/10/what-is-kifastsystemcallret/

Comment: In fact, I think this occurs when an executable is loaded into WinDbg. .lastevent shows: Last event: 1470.12e4: Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

Comment: I'm confused, are you hitting this repeatedly while debugging or just on first attach? If you hit 'k' to get a callstack, what do you see?

Comment: Do you by any change use option to debug all children processes? This is the option `-o` in the command line or `.childdbg 1` in WinDbg. If yes, does it stop once per each child process or more often?

Comment: You are right, I used the -o option. Is it possible to stop breaking each time a process stars and ends. I need the -o option, because I have to debug a child process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it came out that breaks in

```
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b
```

Are when binaries are loaded. You get more than one of this kind of break when you are debugging a process with the -o option, this means, all child processes will be also attached to the debugger. E.g.:

```
windbg.exe -o MyExecutable.exe
```

And breaks in

```
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
```

Are when exeptions occur, e.g.:

```
sxe ld MyBinary.dll
```

But it could be many kinds of exceptions, for more information look at [sx, sxd, sxe, sxi, sxn, sxr, sx-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558822%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) documentation.